YubiKey NEO (U2F) with PAM Passwordless Option w/ Tap - Ubuntu Gnome GDM login not working on Ubuntu 24.04
Installed libpam-u2f, ran pamu2fcfg, touched yubikey and copied output to a file I made (/etc/yubikey_mappings).  Got passwordless with tap(cue) to work on sudo by appending to /etc/pam.d/common-auth or password if no key.
auth    sufficient      pam_u2f.so authfile=/etc/yubikey_mappings cue

Tried doing the same to /etc/pam.d/gdm-password so I can login locally through ubuntu gnome desktop with just the tap of the key, or password if no key. Doesnt seem to work. Heres my file:
#%PAM-1.0
auth    sufficient      pam_u2f.so authfile=/etc/yubikey_mappings cue
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    required        pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success
@include common-auth
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
@include common-account
# SELinux needs to be the first session rule. This ensures that any 
# lingering context has been cleared. Without this it is possible 
# that a module could execute code in the wrong domain.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close
session required        pam_loginuid.so
# SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process
# starts in the proper default security context. Only sessions which are
# intended to run in the user's context should be run after this.
# pam_selinux.so changes the SELinux context of the used TTY and configures
# SELinux in order to transition to the user context with the next execve()
# call.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open
session optional        pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session required        pam_limits.so
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-session
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
@include common-password

Output of tail -f /var/log/auth.log
2024-12-13T00:31:57.190890-06:00 athena-T450 gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm(uid=120) by (uid=0)
2024-12-13T00:31:57.229062-06:00 athena-T450 systemd-logind[1275]: New session c3 of user gdm.
2024-12-13T00:31:57.265244-06:00 athena-T450 (systemd): pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user gdm(uid=120) by gdm(uid=0)
2024-12-13T00:31:59.048278-06:00 athena-T450 polkitd[1251]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c3 (system bus name :1.244 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
2024-12-13T00:32:20.500869-06:00 athena-T450 gdm-smartcard]: pam_sss(gdm-smartcard:auth): User info message: Please insert smart card
2024-12-13T00:32:20.502473-06:00 athena-T450 gdm-smartcard]: pam_sss(gdm-smartcard:auth): User info message: Please (re)insert (different) Smartcard

In the above switched to another tty that launched gnome. Get weird behavior of a blank username and greyed out box. back out. reinsert yubikey, asks for username, enter it in. Says 'Please (re)insert (different)Smartcard'. Dont get any farther. Is this because Ubuntu does something different with GDM-some own spin of GDM-that I need to add something to another file or I changed the wrong file for desktop login?
---new update---
Thought it might be important to note that recently discovered when i close my laptop lid(after having been logged in) and reopen it to get back in (with yubikey still plugged in) it will prompt me to touch my yubikey to get in which works for that part. I get in without issue.

It look like a configuration problem, are you sure in the file /etc/pam.d/gdm-password as the first line you haveauth sufficient pam_u2f.so authfile=/etc/yubikey_mappings cue and also the mapping in /etc/yubikey_mappings must be username:base64_key
If that not fix your problem can you provide your logs with the debug flag auth sufficient pam_u2f.so authfile=/etc/yubikey_mappings cue debug in /etc/pam.d/gdm-password , the logs will be in /var/log/auth.log

appended debug. only thing i might notice is pcscd[2175]: 99999999 auth.c:143:IsClientAuthorized() Process 7201 (user: 1000) is NOT authorized for action: access_card and gnome-shell[11271]: no authentication service is enabled, using password authentication https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wSjkCTGNBc/ . Some weird behavior i recently noticed is when i have the yubikey plugged in and close my laptop lid and reopen, it actually prompts me to press my yubikey to log back in which is a step closer to desired behavior or showing something is partially working.
